# magento2.4.1 setup:di compile error

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1, setup-di-compile

I got a small problem when compiling magento,i.e,

C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-ce-2.4.1-2020-09-25-04-08-02>**php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:di:compile**
Compilation was started.
Plugin list generation... 8/9 [========================>---]  88% 2 mins 382.0 MiB

**In ErrorHandler.php line 61:**

**Warning: Use of undefined constant ‘ - assumed '‘' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)** in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-ce-2.4.1-2020-09-25-04-08-02\ve
ndor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator.php **on line 159**

i have replaced from **$cacheId = implode('|', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "|" . $this->cacheId;** to **$cacheId = implode(‘-’, $this->scopePriorityScheme) . “-” . $this->cacheId;**

**Using materials:-**

**magento 2.4.1**

**xampp/php 7.4.23**

**elasticsearch 7.6.0**

Thanks

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: @MohitPatel 7.4.23

Answer (score 0):

In your magento's root "error_log" or "php_error" file.

here please check what's error in your code

Comment: if not in root than its in php's error log path. depend on server configuratiion

Comment: I **upgraded system php 7.3.5 to 7.4.25**....now its **resolved.**


after completing the magento setup through command prompt...I got **deprecated error** while running **localhost on google** , like

**localhost:82/magento/admin**
its showing below error like this

**Deprecated: The behavior of unparenthesized expressions containing both '.' and '+'/'-' will change in PHP 8: '+'/'-' will take a higher precedence in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator.php on line 161**

Comment: happy to hear it's resolved

Comment: you know the deprecated error.

Comment: your any custom module's plugin must be using depracated method. please check custom modules

Comment: i dont know which module cause deprected error....can you help me

Comment: I've tried many YouTube videos to setup Magento .... but it doesn't help ... Can you suggest me a good link or video on how to set up Magento in one tap.